# Getting can not read the property of undefined error while implementing for each loop in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to loop two different object like the following code example,

```
this.selectedRoomListObj.data.forEach(element => {
            
            this.dataSourceBlockCode.data.forEach(item => 
              {
                this.nPercentageAssigned.push(item.nPercent);
                this.nccpId.push(item.nClientCPCMappingId);
              });
          var weightedAverageRoomObj={
            nPercentageAssigned: this.nPercentageAssigned,
            nccpId: this.nccpId,
            nRoomAllocationId:element.nRoomAllocationId
          };
          console.log(this.weightedAverageRoomObj);
          this.blockcodeService.addWeightAverageRoomApiMethod(this.weightedAverageRoomObj)
          .subscribe(data=> {console.log(data)});

        });
```

And getting error like the following an it points to the line where I am looping selectedRoomListObject- " this.selectedRoomListObj.data.forEach(element => {" this line.

[image]
I tried to troubleshoot by putting console.log for selectedRoomListObj object. And its successfully printing the object data.

My Front-end code for triggering event is as below,

```
<ng-container  style="max-width:40px; ">
                <input #input type="number" [(ngModel)]="element.nPercent" 
(change)="calculateTotalAndAddRecord()" (keyup.enter)="calculateTotalAndAddRecord()" >%
 </ng-container>
```

Troubleshoot Try2

When I tried to console.log(this), I got the console printing like the following,

[image]

Here I am getting selectedRoomListObj , but not showing dataBlockCode object. When I tried to print this.dataBlockCode using console.log , at that time i am getting objects. But not for `this`. And the selectedRoomListObj is already assigning using another function onclicking another button. this 2 functions are calling serially one after another.

The other function definition is ,

```
  assignSelectedRoomRecordsToObject(){
    
    this.selectedRoomListObj =this.checkedDataSource.data;
    
   }
```

Can anyone guide to troubleshoot this problem ? Am I doing wrong syntax in looping ? Or Am I following wrong inner loops?

Comment: I can see a `dispatchEvent` in your call-stack. Is this code getting executed inside any `EventHandler`?

Comment: @NalinRanjan - Yes Offcourse Sir. I called this function on one button click to calculate sum and there after to call one back end API to insert one row. This is working on Onclick event.

Comment: Can you show your event handler registration? I think `this` keyword in your case is pointing to your button and not the object in which these properties are... can you try a `console.log(this)` before this code and inside the handler to see what object it prints...

Comment: @NalinRanjan - Yes I edited the question according to your two points and it results.

Comment: am I reading it correct in your screenshot... `selectedRoomListObj` looks like an `Array` in the screenshot... And then in the code we have, `this.selectedRoomListObj.data.forEach...`. Is it the same object? If it is, then you are doing a `.data...` on an object which is an `Array`... and which should be `undefined` as expected...

Comment: @NalinRanjan - Thank you for your response sir. Yes it is array. So how can change this looping to suite for array object here ?

Comment: Try `this.selectedRoomListObj.forEach...` instead of `this.selectedRoomListObj.data.forEach...`...

Comment: @NalinRanjan - Yes perfect, Its working fine. Please add these all as answer. Let me accept this as answer